# ASP.NET - The name 'Context' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am getting the error in the title above from this line of code:

```
HttpCookie authCookie = Context.Request.Cookies[cookieName];
```

Is there something I forgot to use ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Security.Principal;
```

Comment: You probably want `HttpContext.Current`, however if you're in a controller you should be able to access `Request` directly.

Comment: Based on your namespaces, I've add the ASP.NET-MVC tag.  if this isn't correct, I'll happily revert the edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are in the context of a controller, you should be using `HttpContext`.

```
HttpCookie authCookie = HttpContext.Request.Cookies[cookieName];
```